# Xamarin InitializeComponent() cannot be used when inherited from application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I followed the Xamarin Forms quickstart guide and my only error is:
Error   CS0103  The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.

The app.xaml only seems to generate this error when the class "App" inherits from "Application", when I make it inherit from ContentPage, it works.

The build action of the app.xaml is "Embedded resource" and the custom tool is "MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml". I've tried to run the custom tool on the app.xaml, but it does not work. Also the package Xamarin.Forms is updated to the latest version and I have deleted and readded the app.xaml.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I'm using vs2015 Update 3 and Portable class libraries.

EDIT:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Phoneword
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new Phoneword.MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PhoneWord.App">
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center"       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</Application>
```

Comment: I am not getting this issue on my end. Tested with VS2015 Update 3 and a Blank Xaml App (Xamarin.Forms Portable). Did you try unloading and reloading the PCL project by right clicking on the project in Solution Explorer and choosing "Unload" and after it unloads, do the same selecting "Reload."

Comment: I tried this several times, but it doesn't work. @jgoldberger

Answer (score 0):

You don't give that much information, but my guess is there's a mismatch between base classes

the xaml should start with

```xml
<Application ....
             x:Class="MyApp" >
```

indicating that MyApp inherits from Application.

the code behind should reflect this as well:

```cs
public class MyApp : Application
```

if both base types mismatches, you're in trouble.

Comment: I've added my code. There seems to be no mismatch, I already searched half google for this.